# How to reset nodes back to unbold in treeview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

On Selecting a particular I want to highlight the treepath with nodes as bold one.

```
protected void Trv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HighlightPath(Trv.SelectedNode);
}

private void HighlightPath(TreeNode node)
{
    node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    node.Text = "<div style=font-weight:bold>" + node.Text + "</div>";
    if (node.Parent != null)
    HighlightPath(node.Parent);
}
```

But next time if I am slelecting another node its should mark previous nodes unbold and new path as bolded one. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by stroring all highlighted nodes in a `List<TreeNode>` and before highlighting a new path, you un-highligt the items in the list.

```
// New list of currently highlighted nodes
protected List<TreeNode> highlightedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

protected void Trv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call the method to un-highligt first
    UnHighlightNodes();

    HighlightPath(Trv.SelectedNode);
}

private void UnHighlightNodes()
{
    foreach(var node in highlightedNodes)
    {
        // TODO: code to un-highlight nodes
    }
    // Clear List of highlighted nodes
    highlightedNodes.Clear();
}

private void HighlightPath(TreeNode node)
{
    node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    node.Text = "<div style=font-weight:bold>" + node.Text + "</div>";
    if (node.Parent != null)
    HighlightPath(node.Parent);

    // Store the node in the list of highlighted nodes
    highlightedNodes.Add(node);
}
```

This could be optimized further to prevent un-highlighting and then immediatley highlighting again. Like this:

```
// New list of currently highlighted nodes
protected List<TreeNode> HighlightedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

protected void Trv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodesToHighlight = FindPathToRoot(Trv.SelectedNode).ToList();

    // Un-highlight nodes (except those which should stay highlighted)
    UnHighlightNodes(HighlightedNodes.Except(nodesToHighlight));

    // Highlight nodes (except nodes already highlighted)
    HighlightNodes(nodesToHighlight.Except(HighlightedNodes));

    // Save the new list of highlighted nodes;
    HighlightedNodes = nodesToHighlight;
}

private static IEnumerable<TreeNode> FindPathToRoot(TreeNode node)
{
    do
    {
        yield return node;
        node = node.Parent;
    } while (node != null);
}

private void UnHighlightNodes(IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        // TODO: code to un-highlight nodes
    }
}

private void HighlightNodes(IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
        node.Text = "<div style=font-weight:bold>" + node.Text + "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach (var node in highlightedNodes) this loop is everytime showing 0 count

Comment: This reseting the nodes in List<TreeNode> HighlightedNodes not in the actual treeview trv

Comment: Hi! Yes - the idea in this approach is sorting out which TreeNodes to un-highligt. Were you instead asking how to un-highlight a specific node?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **bold selected node and its Parent node** in a `treeview` asp.net page.
If its so you don't need to make it complex. Please try to put this in your `page load` event as shown .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode ParentNodes in TreeView1.Nodes)
        {
            ParentNodes.Text = ParentNodes.Text.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "");
            foreach (TreeNode ChildNodes in ParentNodes.ChildNodes)
            {
                ChildNodes.Text = ChildNodes.Text.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "");
            }
        }
        TreeNode node = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
        node.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("<b>" + node.Text + "</b>");
        node.Parent.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("<b>" + node.Parent.Text + "</b>");
    }
}
```

Here `TreeView1` is my treeview . You don't need to do anything in `SelectedNodeChanged` event for this.